# Attached tranform controls to centre of group?

Tags: three.js

I am creating One Group and adding Plane and sphere inside that group.
Then I attached Trans Form Controls to that group.
Trans Form control are getting attached to group and if I move the group with Trans From control plane and sphere both are Moving Which is what I wanted.

But Position of transform control is not at the center of Group.

I want exactly like this which I created in ThreeJS Editor.
[image]

What should I do so Transform controls will be at center of Group.
I don't want to change position of my plane or sphere this are important.
One Approached that I tried is
`transformControls.position.set(plane.position.x,plane.position.y,plane.position.z)`

This change the Transfrom control position to centre of Group but does not change Pivot point of transform control which is at center of scene so all my rotations are around that point.

Comment: Do your sphere and plane have a local transformation within the group that could cause their geometry to appear off-center from the group? IF so, you would need to account for this transformation as well, since the group center may be different from the geometric center.

Comment: thanks for the reply @TheJim01 I want TrandForm controls at the center of the group and don't want to change plane and sphere position as they are important. The plane and sphere are at the center of the group.

Comment: I'm not super-familiar with this control, which is why I'm giving this advice as a comment and not an answer: Try copying the `position`, `quaternion`, and `scale` of your `Group` to the `TransformControl` object, then on that object call `updateMatrix()` and `updateMatrixWorld()`. That should apply existing transformations from your group to the transform widget, causing it to snap to the center of the group.

Comment: @TheJim01 ok ok I will try this appraoch